# Write a string to two lines if over 20 characters

Tags: php

I have a varying number of strings (album titles from mp3s), but some of them are over 20 characters long.  They have spaces in them.  I want to be able to find the long ones, and the most central space, and insert a line break in there.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: you must assign some limits for example: all spaces greater than 10 then line break...

Comment: Please post your code of what you've tried.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815040/smarter-word-wrap-in-php-for-long-words for wordwrap() or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363425/how-to-wrap-long-lines-without-spaces-in-html for CSS.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet.  I could write a long foreach that would scan for every string over 20 and then find the closest space, but it would be too drawn out and I want a smooth quick function to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `wordwrap` function.  See the docs at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$longString = "This is a really really long string that exceeds 20 characters";
$longString = wordwrap($longString, 20, "\n"); // or use <br/>
```

Comment: Perfectly work for me : $longString = wordwrap($longString, 20, "<br>"); used <br> to display it on frontend... Thanks! @kami

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array();
$arr = explode(" ", $string);
$display_string = "";

foreach($arr AS $word){
 $length = strlen($display_string) + strlen($word);
 if($length >= 20){
  $display_string .= "<br />".$word." ";
 }else{
  $display_string .= $word." ";
 } 
}
echo $display_string;
```