# wordwrap()... Break only word with specific length

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `wordwrap()` to break the text, but I don't want it to break the text each time it reaches the specific length, I want it to break only the words that exceeds any specific length so for example:

```
<?php

$string = "Some text that will be splited each 15 characters...";
echo wordwrap($string,15,"<br>");
?>
```

Well, it works but I'd like to break only words that exceeded specific length for example:

```
<?php

$string = "This string contains word Entertainment, and this word has 13 characters";
//I want the wordwrap to split only the words that exceed the limit so..
wordwrap($string,10,"<br>");
//Wont work as I expect...
?>
```

What can i do? Thanks!

**My expected outcome is :**

This string contains word Entertainm

ent, and this word has 13 characters

Comment: Can you post what you want the expected outcome to be?

Comment: This question is so unclear. PHP doesn't split the long word when `$cut` (last parameter) is set to `false` which is the default. Set it to `true` if you want to break the word.

Comment: When I set max-width to 100 px E.g, and echo any big word, the word exceeds the width so thats why I want to split only specific word

Comment: @cmo - Added my expected outcome

Comment: Take a look in this 2012 answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815040/smarter-word-wrap-in-php-for-long-words

Comment: I think that may be the answer im looking for (im on phone now),  thanks for now, I'll let u know tomorrow if that worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the last parameter `$cut` to cut long words:

```
wordwrap($string, 10, "<br>", true); // true in the last param cuts long words
```

It defaults to `false` (dont break long words).