# How to insert word-wrap function to auto-break a long word in PHP?

Tags: php, html

How can I insert word-wrap function so that any word that is too long doesn't cut `<div>` border but line-returns itself?

The following is the variable I want to word-wrap

```
$body = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['body']));
```

Comment: To my understanding when text is outputted to the screen it already does a form of wrap-wrap within stuff like `<div>`s. if you've got text that's overlapping with other elements or being cut off i would think the problem lies with your CSS styling

Comment: the paragraph line returns itself in the form but when it is posted it shows the paragraph's long word breaking the 'div'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smarter word-wrap in PHP for long words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815040/smarter-word-wrap-in-php-for-long-words)

Comment: @chris i take it then that by *"breaking the 'div'"* you want the `<div>` to be at a certain size in which case you'd want to set `width` or `hight` and also check that if you have got `overflow` set it's set to `visible` (by default it's visisble)

Comment: someone please just add word-wrap function to the above $body variable. that would be much appreciated