# Smarter string break in PHP string

Tags: php, string, word-break

I wanted to break a string into `max 35 character` but with intelligent break. Suppose i have string below:

```
street name, sector name, city, state, pincode
```

or

```
ABC Heights, Golf Road, City Test, City Sector
```

Now, i want these strings to be break in anyway but it shall be intelligent not to break any wrong line.

Eg. break can be

```
ABC Heights, Golf Road,<br/> 
City Test, City Sector
```

NOT

```
ABC Heights, Golf Road,City Te<br/>
st, City Sector
```

I have tried answers here

[SMart Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815040/smarter-word-wrap-in-php-for-long-words)

but no luck.

Comment: [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) + [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br)

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
<?php
    $string = "ABC Heights, Golf Road, City Test, City Sector";
    echo wordwrap($string, 35, "<br />\n");
?>
```

Which would result in

```
ABC Heights, Golf Road, City Test,
City Sector
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php for more details.

Comment: Can i save this broken string into 2 diff variables

Comment: Yep, just `explode` on the delimiter - in this case `$lines = explode("<br />\n",$wordwrap_string);` Then set $lines[0] / [1] wherever you want them.